# comparing a GUID so I can sort by GUID

Tags: delphi, sorting, guid

what's a nice, fast way to sort a list of GUIDs (as TGuid).  i thought i'd just use SysUtils.CompareMem(P1, P2: Pointer; Length: Integer): Boolean; until i realized it returns boolean.

i'd wish for something comparable to CompareText( ) or CompareValue( ) that return integer so it can be used in a sort comparison.

i suppose not many people wish to sort GUIDs...any ideas?

i suppose i could call make some cascading calls to CompareValue( ) on the contents of the TGuid record.  my instincts tell me there must be a better way!

thank you!

Comment: May I ask why you are trying to sort by GUID?

Comment: Microsoft GUID's (I assume thats what you are talking about) are ordered by time of creation, that's quite an interesting property. Ofcourse ordering by time of creation must occur for GUID's belonging to the same machine. Or if the machines in the network are well synchronized it could be used in this way; this implies the non-timestamp elements are not used for the sorting.

Comment: Mike C. - a sort order is very useful for general algorithms and collections. Consider a set collection which needs guaranteed bounded performance - a balanced tree would be suitable, but it needs some arbitrary sorting order.

Comment: thanks Barry!  i'm using it for sorting a collection so i can find things in the list faster.  everything is linked in the database with GUIDs.  i'd like it to be really fast.

since the GUIDs are coming from a database and possibly from any machine anywhere, i simply wish to sort it by any sort order.

Comment: I'd like to suggest that instead of sorting, you may want to use a hash-table structure. An elementary sum and modulus should provide a reasonable distribution; and you should get better performance out of it provided you can determine your number of buckets acurrately enough.

Comment: See also (later question, but "standard" solution) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012581/delphi-7-tguid-compare

Comment: @GerryColl the IsEqualGuid only returns boolean...i'd need integer so it can be sorted based on that information.  thank you for your answer anyway.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're using Delphi 2009 or better, you can use `TComparer<TGUID>.Compare()`, or the `BinaryCompare` function it calls, from the Generics.Defaults unit.

Comment: very smooth barry--thank you!  i knew there must be something i could use for this in the RTL!

Answer (score 2):

I do not know Delphi but generally a GUID is a [128-bit hexadecimal string](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/06/27/8659071.aspx), you can just cast/parse the sub-elements to unsigned (4 * 4-byte or 2*8-byte) integers and then compare them. Once you have that function just apply a standard sort algorithm.

If my answer does not satisfy the RFC of the GUID [specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) Microsoft uses is presented here, you can probably come up with better ways of sorting extracting the bit-level data in the GUID.

Comment: This is the best option if < Delphi 2009 as a string comparison too expensive.  Just have your routine bail early as soon as a missmatch is found since for a majority of these it won't be necessary to sort much past the first or second element.

Answer (score 0):

Use GUIDToString and do CompareStr on that -- not the fastest option but it works.

Comment: Ouch...string comparisons are VERY expensive. Better to sort against the TGUID elements individually, or cast to an array of [1..8] integer and compare the arra

Answer (score -3):

```
Function CompareGUIDS( pvGUID1, pvGUID2 : TGUID ) : Boolean;
 Begin
   If ( pvGUID1.D1    = pvGUID2.D1 )    And
      ( pvGUID1.D2    = pvGUID2.D2 )    And
      ( pvGUID1.D3    = pvGUID2.D3 )    And
      ( pvGUID1.D4[ 0 ] = pvGUID2.D4[ 0 ] ) And
      ( pvGUID1.D4[ 1 ] = pvGUID2.D4[ 1 ] ) And
      ( pvGUID1.D4[ 2 ] = pvGUID2.D4[ 2 ] ) And
      ( pvGUID1.D4[ 3 ] = pvGUID2.D4[ 3 ] ) And
      ( pvGUID1.D4[ 4 ] = pvGUID2.D4[ 4 ] ) And
      ( pvGUID1.D4[ 5 ] = pvGUID2.D4[ 5 ] ) And
      ( pvGUID1.D4[ 6 ] = pvGUID2.D4[ 6 ] ) And
      ( pvGUID1.D4[ 7 ] = pvGUID2.D4[ 7 ] ) Then
      Result := True
   Else
      Result := False;
 End;
```

Comment: X-Ray was looking for a function that compares GUIDs (equals, greater than, lesser than). Not for a function that matches GUIDs.