# Delphi 7 tguid compare

Tags: delphi, compare, guid, delphi-7

Is any other way to compare 2 TGUID elements, except transform them into strings (the guidtostring function) and after evaluate the expression, in Delphi 7?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [IsEqualGUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680575%28VS.85%29.aspx) API declared in [SysUtils](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.IsEqualGUID).

Answer (score 5):

IsEqualGUID() (or IsEqualIID()), like TOndrej suggested.  You can also use SysUtuils. CompareMem() instead, since TGuid is a binary array of bytes.

Comment: As a side note: A GUID is NOT an array of bytes, it is a packed structure with DWORDS, WORDS and BYTES with a total length of 16 bytes. You can lookup the structure by checking out the TGUID type.

Comment: My point was that it is a fixed-length binary data type without any padding, so CompareMem() will work as an alternative to IsEqualGUID(), ie: `CompareMem(@Guid1, @Guid2, SizeOf(TGuid))`.

Comment: ... and `CompareMem()` seems to be slightly faster.